# Cluster markers are not clearing in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, cluster-computing

I have used cluster concept in my application, i can successfully get the cluster but the problem is not getting updated when the array of markers getting refreshed, right now based on the miles i am refreshing my map

Check it out my below code :

```
if (map != null) {

            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(list.get(0).getLatitude()),
                            Double.parseDouble(list.get(0).getLangtitude())),
                    map.getCameraPosition().zoom));

            mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(getActivity(), map);

            map.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
            map.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);

        }
        mClusterManager.clearItems();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            String title = list.get(i).getName() + "~" + list.get(i).getCity()
                    + "~" + list.get(i).getSector();

            MyItem offsetItem = new MyItem(Double.parseDouble(list.get(i)
                    .getLatitude()), Double.parseDouble(list.get(i)
                    .getLangtitude()), title, list.get(i).getSector(),
                    String.valueOf(i));

            mClusterManager.addItem(offsetItem);
        }
        mClusterManager.cluster();
```

Instead of updating markers are added for each refreshment, `mClusterManager.clearItems();` its not working, dont know what mistake i have done, please figure out
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to clear all markers, use `clearItems()`.

If you want to remove individual marker,obtain its reference ans use `remove()` method.

Answer (score 2):

I had same probleme and i solve them with this issue :

```
  mClusterManager.clearItems();
    mClusterManager.cluster();

//fill with data

       new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mClusterManager.cluster();
                }
            }, 100);
```

Comment: Before this answer i totally recreating cluster manager on each data update. Also, view.post {..} didn`t help. Only post with delay 100 ms. Thank you!

Comment: You are calling `.cluster()` twice?

Comment: Yes. first without data and second after filling data